# Counting the number of rows that equal specific value using awk

Tags: awk

I have a file with 12 or so columns. I want to find the the total number of rows in column 3 that don't start with #N/A.

Column 3 looks like this and is approximately 1000 lines long:

```
Data_3
-0.792363849
-1.036163943
-0.98661685
-1.156351406
-0.800122982
-1.079449157
#N/A
1.612877252
1.638385406
```

So for the example above, the output should be 8.
I could begin by counting how many rows begins with #N/A and just subtract from the total number of rows. I have tried the command below which worked fine. But is there an easier way to count the number of rows not including #NA. How would I modify the awk script.

```
awk '($3 == "#N/A") {count++} END {print count}' file
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for "count all _except_ NA", change the `==` to `!=`. Otherwise, it's about as good as it gets.

Comment: does your data file contain a header record (ie, does the 1st line of your file include the string `Data_3`)?

Answer (score 1):

You could replace == with != to count lines not containing #N/A

Answer (score 1):

idk about easier but the most obvious 2 robust ways to do what you want are:

```
awk '(NR > 1) && ($3 == "#N/A") {count++} END {print (count ? (NR-1) - count : 0)}' file
awk '(NR > 1) && ($3 != "#N/A") {count++} END {print count+0}' file
```

The math in both scripts is to accommodate possibly empty files and make sure the header line is skipped.

I'm assuming above that, based on the code you provided, when you said `start with #N/A` in  the question you actually meant `are equal to #N/A`. If you truly DID mean `start with #N/A` then change `== "#N/A"` to `~ /^#N\/A/` and change `!= "#N/A"` to `!~ /^#N\/A/`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution without `awk`:

```
cut -f3 file | tail -n +2 | grep -cv '#N/A'
```

The command [`cut`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) with option `-f3` cuts the 3rd column, TAB-delimited by default.
`tail -n +2` : print from line 2 onward.

Here, [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) uses the following options:
`-v` : Print lines that do **not** match.
`-c` : Print count of matching lines.

Answer (score 1):

> counting how many rows begins with #N/A and just subtract from the
> total number of rows.

If you want to implement this behavior to your current code and there is always 1 line header, do

```
awk '($3 == "#N/A") {count++} END {print NR-1-count}' file
```

where `-1` is for header line, `NR` is built-in variable, number of row, inside `END` it is number of last row processed (i.e. total number of rows processed). If you want to know more read [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: That would print `-1` instead of `0` for an empty input file.